# NET 6 - Nullability of reference types warning

Tags: c#, nullable, .net-6.0

In NET 6, I have a repository asynchronously returns string, which may be sourced from REST API or text file. Since the result could be null, the return type is nullable string in a task `Task<string?>`:

```cs
public interface IFooRepository
{
    Task<string?> FetchAsync(string path);
}
```

One of a concrete class of the repository would look like:

```cs
public class FooRepository : IFooRepository
{
    public async Task<string?> FetchAsync(string path)
    {
        string? result = null;

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            result = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Next, I added a mock repository class used by the unit test. This simply returns the constant value. (Obviously, it will never return null.)

```cs
public class MockFooRepository : IFooRepository
{
    public Task<string?> FetchAsync(string path)
    {
        string? result = "ok!";
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

After adding the mock repository, I started to receive the warning message:

> Nullability of reference types in value of type 'Task' doesn't match target type 'Task<string?>'.

To take care the warning, I prefer not to *hide* the warning message using preprocessor directives `#pragma warning disable CS8619`.

Instead, what would be the right way to handle the issue?

Comment: @KirkWoll thanks for pointing it out. I've edited it.

Comment: You can also remove <Nullable>enable</Nullable> from the csproj file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify the generic argument yourself when calling FromResult

```
return Task.FromResult<string?>(result);
```

Comment: Or, indeed, `Task.FromResult((string?) result)` (of course we can elide `result` and directly use `Task<string?> FetchAsync(string path) => Task.FromResult((string?) "ok!")`, which is not only shorter but possibly less confusing as well).